# how can I use jQuery to select image within a clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML. Notice I have an h3 tag with an image

```
<h3 class="title" id="1">Metal Roof Colors <img src="/sites/default/files/arrow-white.png" class="title-img flip"></h3>
```

I have 4 titles like that and I need to rotate only the image on the clicked title. Following is my jQuery, but it flips all four images. I can't figure it out.

```
if($(window).innerWidth() <= 775) {
    $('.expand').addClass('hidden');
        $('.title').on('click', func);
            function func(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                    $('.title-img').toggleClass('flip');
                    $(this).next('.expand').toggleClass('hidden');
            }
    }
```

Comment: $(this).find("img")....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you currently select all matching elements by class:

```
$('.title-img')
```

Filter that by the clicked element:

```
$('.title-img', this)
```

Or perhaps something like:

```
$(this).find('.title-img')
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
if ($(window).innerWidth() <= 775) {
  $('.expand').addClass('hidden');
  $('.title').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find(".title-img").toggleClass('flip');
    $(this).next('.expand').toggleClass('hidden');
  });

}
```

**[Here is the JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/23z0dume/)**